# Why is this not using index?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this basic query:

```
SELECT B.sap_adjustment_id,b.adjustment_type,'PROCESSED'
FROM mtl_material_transactions a
    RIGHT JOIN xxcb_RTL_adjustments_iface b ON a.attribute1=b.sap_adjustment_id
WHERE b.interface_status='NEW'
    AND b.adjustment_type='ADJUSTMENT'
```

As you Oracle e-Business Suite users know, mtl_material_transactions table is generally one of the biggest tables in the database.

I am joining to it on attribute1 from a custom table.

mtl_material_transactions has a number indexes, but I created one on attribute1 in an attempt to speed up the run time.

```
INFO    INDEX_NAME          UNIQUE  LOGGING DEGREE  COLUMN_NAME     POSITION    ORDER   OWNER
PLAIN   XXCB_MTL_TRX_ATTR1  N       YES     1       ATTRIBUTE1                  Asc     APPS
```

But when I run explain plan, I still get full table scans and index is not used.

```
Plan                                                                Cost    
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWS                                          442,861 
    3 HASH JOIN OUTER                                               442,861 
        1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE APPS.XXCB_RTL_ADJUSTMENTS_IFACE   35  
        2 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE INV.MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS     442,715
```

How should I change the index so that its used by this query?

Comment: You don't actually _use_ any columns from `a` that I can see. Perhaps the engine is seeing that as well and thus doesn't use the index? Does the plan change if you include columns from `a` in your select?

Comment: I think(?) there's nothing you can specifically do on your end with indices, rather than let Oracle do it's "magic" in the background. One issue with the approach though, regardless: the more indices you add to a table, the less helpful they'll be.

Comment: Another possibility: The coverage of this query (meaning how many rows of `a` it hits) is so high that it's cheaper to scan the whole table than to use the index (jumping back and forth between the index hits and the actual table data).

Comment: Did you create `attribute1` index on both tables?

Comment: It would have been better to show the complete, original execution plan that includes the row estimates rather than some stripped down sample

Comment: What is the best way to do that in Toad?  I couldn't figure out how to export and post it in a easy to read format.

Comment: But anyway the point was to demonstrate that I was getting full table scans on both tables.  Row estimates are inconsequential in this scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is this not using index?

Because `MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS.ATTRIBUTE1` is a `VARCHAR2` field and, judging by its name, the `XXCB_RTL_ADJUSTMENTS_IFACE.SAP_ADJUSTMENT_ID` is *probably* a `NUMBER` field.

That means, Oracle is doing an implicit type conversion to process the query and, so, is actually evaluating *this* join condition instead of the one you wrote:

```
ON TO_NUMBER(a.attribute1)=b.sap_adjustment_id
```

The `TO_NUMBER()` function that Oracle is implicitly wrapping around the column prevents it from using the index on that column.

Instead, try writing it this way:

```
ON a.attribute1=TO_CHAR(b.sap_adjustment_id)
```

Comment: Matthew - Absolutely correct 100% on point.  The explain plan is using the index now and the query run time dropped from a couple of minutes down to 85 milliseconds on first execution.  Thank you.